Show $f(X) = X^n + aX + b$ has $f'(\alpha_i)=\frac{-n(a\alpha_i+b)+a\alpha_i}{\alpha_i}$.
I have the polynomial $f(X) = X^n + aX + b$, which has roots $\alpha_i$.
I want to show that $$
f'(\alpha_i)=\frac{-n(a\alpha_i+b)+a\alpha_i}{\alpha_i}$$
for all $i$, as given in this answer.
How can we do this?
We can see that $f’(X) = nX^{n-1} + a$, but this is no good as we lose the $b$.
We can also do $(Xf(X))’ = Xf’(X) + f(X) = (n+1)X^n + 2aX + b$. We may plug in $X = \alpha_i$, and note that $f(\alpha_i) = 0$, to get an expression involving $a$ and $b$. It doesn’t match though, as we get an $\alpha_i^{n-1}$ after dividing through by $\alpha_i$, which does not match.
I’ve tried similar expressions $(X^i f(X))’$ but am struggling to get everything to match up.
What am I missing?

As you said, $$f'(X)=nX^{n-1}+a.$$ Moreover, $$\alpha _i^n+a\alpha _i+b=0\implies \alpha _i^n=-a\alpha _i-b.\tag{1}$$
So $$f'(\alpha _i)=na\alpha _i^{n-1}+a=\frac{na\alpha _i^n+\alpha _ia}{\alpha _i}.$$
Using $(1)$ allows you to conclude.
